# Alter arguments in custom command

Tags: conditionals, ifthenelse

I would like to modify my func command in such a way that the domain/codomain arguments can be altered, e.g. so that arg=R^n yields $\mathbb{R}^n$.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}    
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts}
\usepackage{array}  
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{ifthen}



\newcommand{\func}[4]%
{%  
    \arraycolsep=1.5pt
    \begin{array}{rl}   
        #1
        :
        \ifthenelse{\equal{#2}{N}}{\mathbb{N}}{}%
        \ifthenelse{\equal{#2}{Z}}{\mathbb{Z}}{}%
        \ifthenelse{\equal{#2}{Q}}{\mathbb{Q}}{}%
        \ifthenelse{\equal{#2}{R}}{\mathbb{R}}{}%
        \ifthenelse{\equal{#2}{C}}{\mathbb{C}}{}%
        \ifthenelse{\equal{#2}{K}}{\mathbb{K}}{}%
        \ifthenelse{\equal{#2}{F}}{\mathbb{F}}{}%
        \ifthenelse{
            \not\equal{#2}{N} 
            \AND
            \not\equal{#2}{Z} 
            \AND
            \not\equal{#2}{Q} 
            \AND
            \not\equal{#2}{R} 
            \AND
            \not\equal{#2}{C} 
            \AND
            \not\equal{#2}{K} 
            \AND
            \not\equal{#2}{F} 
        }
        {#2}{}%
        & \longrightarrow 
        \ifthenelse{\equal{#3}{N}}{\mathbb{N}}{}%
        \ifthenelse{\equal{#3}{Z}}{\mathbb{Z}}{}%
        \ifthenelse{\equal{#3}{Q}}{\mathbb{Q}}{}%
        \ifthenelse{\equal{#3}{R}}{\mathbb{R}}{}%
        \ifthenelse{\equal{#3}{C}}{\mathbb{C}}{}%
        \ifthenelse{\equal{#3}{K}}{\mathbb{K}}{}%
        \ifthenelse{\equal{#3}{F}}{\mathbb{F}}{}% 
        \ifthenelse{
            \not\equal{#3}{N} 
            \AND
            \not\equal{#3}{Z} 
            \AND
            \not\equal{#3}{Q} 
            \AND
            \not\equal{#3}{R} 
            \AND
            \not\equal{#3}{C} 
            \AND
            \not\equal{#3}{K} 
            \AND
            \not\equal{#3}{F} 
        }
        {#3}{}%
        \\
    x   &\longmapsto #4
    \end{array}
}


%_________________________________

\begin{document}
    $\func{f}{R}{C}{f(x)}$

    $\func{f}{R}{C^*}{f(x)}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Also, if there's a smarter way to write what I have done so far, any advice is welcome.

Thanks

**Edit:**

Aside from simply defining a shorthand for the bb characters, as suggested in the comments (and which I may go for in the end), I find that Andrew's solution works fine for me so far, with a minor adjusment

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{array}

\newcommand{\func}[4]{%
    \arraycolsep=1.5pt
    \begin{array}{rl}
        #1\colon{\mathbb #2}&\longrightarrow{\mathbb #3}\\
        x&\longmapsto #4
    \end{array}%
}
\begin{document}

    $\func{f}{R_+}{R_+}
    {
            \begin{cases}
            x^3&, x\in \mathbb{Q}  \\
            0&,x\notin \mathbb{Q}   
            \end{cases}
    }$


\end{document}
```

[image]

Since Daleif's answer allows for other character types, and therefore useful to more people, I'll move the tick to his post.

Comment: You could use something like: `\def\func#1^#2{\mathbb{#1}^{#2}}`...

Comment: *Also, if there's a smarter way to write what I have done so far, any advice is welcome.* Yes, there is a smarter/simpler way: define `\newcommand{\nR}{\mathbb{R}}` (and slmilarly for the other letters you need) and use `\nR` instead of trying to coax the macro to do difficult substitutions. What if you want a function having domain `Z(g)` (the zero set of g)? Use semantic markup, not tricks.

Comment: @egreg True, _:), that works as well, and is much simpler way to do it. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, you can do it with much shorter code using `xparse`. No need of if then, we simply use the `\str_case_e:nnF` macro from `expl3`.

Edit: As Manuel mentioned in the comments, it is better to grab the first item of the input by running the helper without braces. Then `C^*` also gets converter into `\mathbb{C}^*`.  The obvious reason for splitting into cases, would be if some was to use `\mathbb` others `\mathcal` etc.

```
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand\funcHelper{m}{
   \str_case_e:nnF { #1 }
   {
     {N}{\mathbb{N}}
     {Z}{\mathbb{Z}}
     {Q}{\mathbb{Q}}
     {R}{\mathbb{R}}
     {C}{\mathbb{C}}
     {K}{\mathbb{K}}
     {F}{\mathbb{F}}
   }{
     #1
   }
}
\NewDocumentCommand\func{mmmm}
 {
    \arraycolsep=1.5pt
    \begin{array}{rl}   
        #1
        :
        \funcHelper#2
        & \longrightarrow
        \funcHelper#3
        \\
        x & \longmapsto #4
      \end{array}
    }
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

Comment: Why `-1`, wouldn't it be `1`? `R^n` has `R` in position `1`. *Edit*: it seems simpler to just use `\funcHelper#2` so that it grabs the first token only, and substitutes it with `\mathbb{..}` accordingly.

Comment: @Manuel I stole it from somewhere else. I guess in this case we could just use `#1` as the first argument to the case function. As far as I understand the - 1 just takes the last token in the given argument, which was what was needed in the case where I took it from.

Comment: For this case, I would use `1` rather than `-1` (but it's not important), together with `\funcHelper#2` rather than `\funcHelper{#2}`, that way you can write `R`, `Q^2`, etc.

Comment: @Manuel I'm not a pc until tomorrow, feel free to dit the answer, sounds very reasonable

Comment: @daleif  Thanks for all that. For some reason, your code doesn't work on my end: C^* still gets printed as a non bb character. Is xparse the only supplementary package that I need?

Comment: @Chris, I think I missed that one, as Manuel mentioned it might be better to use 1 instead of -1 and use the helper without the braces, will test tomorrow

Comment: @daleif ok, works now. And yes, I haven't thought about the mathcal case, in particular, which I will possibly need.

Answer (score 2):

Daleif's answer is very pretty and is a really nice demonstration of the power of LaTeX3! On the other hand, I prefer a minimalist approach:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts}
\usepackage{array}

\newcommand\func[3]{%
  \begin{array}{r@{}l}
    #1\colon{\mathbb #2}&\longrightarrow{\mathbb #3}\\
        x&\longmapsto #1(x)
  \end{array}%
}

\begin{document}
  $\func{f}{R}{C}$

  $\func{f}{R}{C^*}$
\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image]

A few comments:

- The fourth argument in the OP is redundant as it is the same as `#1`
- The first character in `#1` and `#2` will be typeset in `\mathbb`, whether or not this makes sense but this fits with all of the examples in the OP so I think that's OK
- I didn't know about `\longmapsto` so this question was useful to me!
- It is better to use `\colon` than `:`
- I added `@{}` to the `array` to gobble some extra space before the arrows

**Edit**

Using [xparse](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/xparse) you can have an optional fourth argument, that defaults to `#1`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{array}

\NewDocumentCommand\func{ mmm O{#1}}{%
  \begin{array}{rl}
    #1\colon{\mathbb #2}&\longrightarrow{\mathbb #3}\\
        x&\longmapsto #4(x)
  \end{array}%
}

\begin{document}
  $\func{f}{R}{C^n}$

  $\func{f}{R}{C^*}$

  $\func{f}{R}{C^*}[g]$
\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image]

It is slightly non-standard having the default argument at the end, so you might want to use

```
\NewDocumentCommand\func{ O{#2}mmm }{%
  \begin{array}{rl}
    #2\colon{\mathbb #3}&\longrightarrow{\mathbb #4}\\
        x&\longmapsto #1(x)
  \end{array}%
}
```

instead but I would put the optional argument at the end as this looks more natural to me.

Comment: Aren't you missing the non bb case, if #2 or #3 is not one of the named, then don't apply bb. The OP just did not show this in the usecases

Comment: Yay, such simplicity is seductive indeed. And  (@ daleif) I don't thinking I'll ever need to use non bb characters, so that'll work fine that way. With respect to your first remark though, I will want to explicitly define functions, so a fourth argument wouldn't be redundant. About your third point, cool ;)! About the fourth: why so? And as for the last: ok, that might come in handy, although I personally do like the spacing without it.

Comment: @daleif As I said in  my second dot point, the first characters in `#2` and `#3` will always be typeset using `\mathbb`. This fits the requirements of the question but may not be what is required in general. Personally, I use `\C` for `\mathbb{C}` etc. so this issue would not arise for me.

Comment: @Chris Using `\colon` is better than `:` because TeX automatically puts the "right" spacing around it. In practice, one might need a magnifying glass to see the difference! If the  function name might change I would have an optional fourth argument that defaults to `#1`, which you can do using [xparse](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/xparse). I'll edit to show what I mean

Comment: @Andrew alright, thanks for the info (\colon). As for the function definition, it isn't that the function name should vary, in my case at least...I'll edit my post as well.